# vue-test-utils shallowMount: execution time grows each test

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

**Problem**

I'm using Vue 2.4 with Mocha and Chai for unit testing. When executing the component tests, the execution time of each test is longer than of the test before.

**Expectation**

That each call of `shallow`/`shallowMount` takes not more than 200ms.

**Files**

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "client",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node ./server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --require test/setup.js src/**/*.spec.js src/*.spec.js --timeout 10000",
    "test:watch": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --require test/setup.js src/**/*.spec.js src/*.spec.js --watch --timeout 10000",
    "test:e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn build"
  },
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
      "html"
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "dist"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-js": "^9.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "execa": "^0.8.0",
    "express-force-ssl": "^0.3.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "onsenui": "^2.6.1",
    "query-string": "^5.0.0",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "validator": "^9.4.1",
    "vue": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-browserupdate": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.3.0",
    "vue-mq": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-onsenui": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-stash": "^2.0.1-beta",
    "vue-touch": "next",
    "vuex": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-spies": "^1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.2.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "jsdom": "^11.8.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "mocha": "^5.1.1",
    "mocha-webpack": "^1.1.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "standard": "^11.0.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "vueify": "^9.4.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

The setup the component tests as easily as possible, we use a fixture class (`VueComponentTestFixture`):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { shallow, mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

import chai from 'chai'
import spies from 'chai-spies'
chai.use(spies)

import messages from '../../src/locale/index'

Vue.use(VueI18n)
const i18n = new VueI18n({ locale: 'de', messages, silentTranslationWarn: true })
Vue.use(Vuex)

// Prevent warnings during tests
// https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/243#issuecomment-288467099
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'v-ons-toolbar',
  'v-ons-toolbar-button',
  'v-ons-search-input',
  'v-touch',
  'v-ons-dialog',
  'v-ons-list',
  'v-ons-list-item',
  'v-ons-page',
  'v-ons-list-header',
  'v-ons-icon',
  'v-ons-modal',
  'ons-list-item',
  'v-ons-select',
  'v-ons-input',
  'v-ons-radio',
  'ons-alert-dialog-button',
  'ons-list',
  'v-ons-button',
  'v-ons-checkbox',
]

const localVue = createLocalVue()

// Prevent a lot of "[vuex] unknown mutation type .." logs during tests
const originalConsoleError = console.error
console.error = function(msg) {
  if(msg.startsWith('[vuex] unknown')) return
  originalConsoleError(msg)
}

export default class VueComponentTestFixture {
  state = {}
  actions = {}
  getters = {}
  mutations = {}
  props = {}
  onsen = {
    notification: {
      alert: chai.spy(),
      confirm: chai.spy(),
      toast: chai.spy()
    }
  }
  mq = {}

  constructor(componentInstance) {
    this.component = componentInstance
  }

  buildWrapper() {
    const startTime = Date.now()
    // custom plugin mocks
    Vue.prototype.$mq = this.mq
    Vue.prototype.$ons = this.onsen

    // build test store
    let store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: this.state,
      actions: this.actions,
      getters: this.getters,
      mutations: this.mutations
    })

    // build component wrapper using shallow rendering
    let wrapper = shallow(this.component, { store, localVue, i18n, propsData: this.props })
    console.log(`buildWrapper mount: ${(Date.now() - startTime)}ms`)
    return wrapper
  }
}
```

Example of a test file:

```
import VueComponentTestFixture from '../../test/components/VueComponentTestFixture'
import chai from 'chai'
import spies from 'chai-spies'
chai.use(spies)
const expect = chai.expect

import Input from './Input.vue'

describe('Input.vue spy', () => {
  let fixture
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = new VueComponentTestFixture(Input)
    wrapper = fixture.buildWrapper()
  })

  it('correctly emits NUMBER type values', () => {
    // Arrange
    wrapper.setProps({
      isEditable: true,
      value: undefined,
      number: undefined,
      type: 'NUMBER',
      title: 'test'
    })
    const input = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="number-input"]')
    const value = 100

    // Act
    input.element.value = value
    input.trigger('input')
    wrapper.find('[data-test-id="save-button"]').trigger('click')

    // Assert
    expect(wrapper.emitted().change[0][0]).to.equal(value)
  })

  it('correctly emits TEXT type values', () => {
    // Arrange
    wrapper.setProps({
      isEditable: true,
      value: undefined,
      number: undefined,
      type: 'TEXT',
      title: 'test'
    })
    const input = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="text-input"]')
    const value = 'test'

    // Act
    input.element.value = value
    input.trigger('input')
    wrapper.find('[data-test-id="save-button"]').trigger('click')

    // Assert
    expect(wrapper.emitted().change[0][0]).to.equal(value)
  })

  it("doesn't emit when not editable", () => {
    // Arrange
    wrapper.setProps({
      isEditable: false,
      value: undefined,
      number: undefined,
      type: 'NUMBER',
      title: 'test'
    })
    const input = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="number-input"]')
    const value = 100

    // Act
    input.element.value = value
    input.trigger('input')
    wrapper.find('[data-test-id="save-button"]').trigger('click')

    // Assert
    expect(wrapper.emitted()).to.be.empty
    expect(input.attributes().disabled).to.equal('disabled')
  })
})
```

Here is the output when executing the tests (with the time measurement in the fixture):

```
  EventEditor.vue basics
    ✓ name present
    ✓ data present

  EventEditor.vue spy
    modulePath module
buildWrapper mount: 110ms
buildWrapper mount: 89ms
      ✓ dispatches "createEvent" when clicking on an enabled eventType button (210ms)
buildWrapper mount: 164ms
      ✓ doesn't dispatch "createEvent" when clicking on a disabled eventType button (161ms)
buildWrapper mount: 230ms
buildWrapper mount: 262ms
      ✓ emits "change" correctly when event is added (515ms)
buildWrapper mount: 310ms
buildWrapper mount: 365ms
      ✓ needs a confirmation for removing an event (720ms)
buildWrapper mount: 409ms
buildWrapper mount: 457ms
      ✓ shows finish timeline button correctly (460ms)
buildWrapper mount: 515ms
      ✓ emits "request-close-timeline" correctly when finish timeline button is clicked (504ms)
    modulePath events
buildWrapper mount: 574ms
buildWrapper mount: 682ms
      ✓ dispatches "createEvent" when clicking on an enabled eventType button (1325ms)
buildWrapper mount: 682ms
      ✓ doesn't dispatch "createEvent" when clicking on a disabled eventType button (678ms)
buildWrapper mount: 728ms
buildWrapper mount: 775ms
      ✓ emits "change" correctly when event is added (1546ms)
buildWrapper mount: 843ms
buildWrapper mount: 899ms
      ✓ needs a confirmation for removing an event (1846ms)
buildWrapper mount: 954ms
buildWrapper mount: 1081ms
      ✓ shows finish timeline button correctly (1082ms)
buildWrapper mount: 1220ms
      ✓ emits "request-close-timeline" correctly when finish timeline button is clicked (1245ms)

  Home component
    ✓ name present
    ✓ components present

  Input.vue spy
buildWrapper mount: 1137ms
    ✓ correctly emits NUMBER type values (2215ms)
buildWrapper mount: 1181ms
    ✓ correctly emits TEXT type values (2215ms)
buildWrapper mount: 1177ms
    ✓ doesn't emits when not editable

  ObservationDialog.vue spy
buildWrapper mount: 1236ms
    ✓ sets locations correctly
buildWrapper mount: 1278ms
    ✓ enables continue buttons only if valid data is given
buildWrapper mount: 1345ms
    ✓ dispatches action "createTimeline"
buildWrapper mount: 1404ms
    ✓ resets form values when createTimeline is called
buildWrapper mount: 1443ms
    ✓ contains all eventTypes in "event selection" when no module is selected
buildWrapper mount: 1467ms
    ✓ removes eventTypes from "event selection" when a module is selected
    method createTimeline
buildWrapper mount: 1547ms
buildWrapper mount: 1581ms
      ✓ dispatches no action when no variant is selected
buildWrapper mount: 1616ms
buildWrapper mount: 1675ms
      ✓ dispatches "createTimeline" when module variant is selected
buildWrapper mount: 1758ms
buildWrapper mount: 1836ms
      ✓ dispatches "loadObservationEvents" when event variant is selected
buildWrapper mount: 1873ms
buildWrapper mount: 2133ms
      ✓ dispatches "createTimeline" and "loadObservationEvents" when both variants are selected
buildWrapper mount: 2953ms
buildWrapper mount: 2445ms
      ✓ commits no mutations when no variant is selected
buildWrapper mount: 2349ms
buildWrapper mount: 2099ms
      ✓ commits the expected mutations when module variant is selected
buildWrapper mount: 2835ms
buildWrapper mount: 2654ms
      ✓ commits the expected mutations when event variant is selected
buildWrapper mount: 3052ms
buildWrapper mount: 2722ms
      ✓ commits only resetPageStack when module and events observation is selected
buildWrapper mount: 3129ms
buildWrapper mount: 2988ms
      ✓ commits the expected mutations when both variants are selected

  ObservationMenu.vue basics
    ✓ name present
    ✓ data present
    ✓ computed present

  ObservationMenu.vue spy
buildWrapper mount: 3490ms
    ✓ sets timelines correctly
buildWrapper mount: 3225ms
    ✓ opens dialog correctly (2440ms)
buildWrapper mount: 2658ms
    ✓ triggers activeModule mutation on state when open existing new timeline (2768ms)
buildWrapper mount: 4084ms
    ✓ triggers activeModule mutation on state when open existing finished timeline (3000ms)

  Select.vue
    ✓ name present
    ✓ props present
    ✓ data present

  Select.vue spy
buildWrapper mount: 2724ms
    ✓ shows only prefered options
buildWrapper mount: 2714ms
    ✓ opens modal (2925ms)

  state
    ✓ commit reset action
    ✓ empties the page stack
    mutation navigateToTimeline
      ✓ adds a "module observation" page to the beginning of the pageStack array
      ✓ adds an "event observation" page to the end of the pageStack array


  50 passing (2m)
```

It can be seen how the time consumed by `buildWrapper` "stacks up" each test. I tried it with `beta-14` of `vue-test-utils` as also with `beta-20`, same result.

I think the component(s) itself are not of interest. It happens also when only executing the tests of each component separately. But if it is necessary, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve the issue, but here are a couple of things I've been doing:

1. Group tests that are "non-destructive" (i.e. tests that only determine presence or absence of elements, without any clicking or data-filling, check snapshot validity, etc.) into a single sub-describe 
   e.g.

```
describe('main', () => {
    describe('non-destructive', () => { ... });
    describe('destructive', () => { ... });
});
```

each of the describes can have its own set of beforeEach/afterEach, beforeAll/afterAll hooks.

2. In the case of non-destructive tests, use `beforeAll` instead of `beforeEach`, as the mounting will only need to happen once
3. For destructive tests, add `afterEach()` hook which will call `wrapper.destroy()` to ensure tests clean up after themselves:

```
 afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.destroy();
  });
```

You can add here any other cleanups, e.g. if you're mocking axios, it's a good idea to do `mockedAxios.resetHistory();` here